# ¿Es útil Git para trabajar individualmente?

Tags: git

No soy usuario de Git, he leído sobre él y me parece interesante, pero por lo que he leído sus ventajas (o su utilidad) es para trabajo en grupo sobre un mismo proyecto.

Yo trabajo solo, desarrollo webs a medida pero de manera individual, solo yo tengo acceso y modifico el código. Mi pregunta es: **¿Tendría Git en este caso alguna utilidad para mi?**

Comment: Utilizas más de un ordenador? O trabajas directamente sobre web.

Comment: te serviría más que nada para ver las versiones que vayas subiendo y tener un control de ellas, por si en algún caso tuvieras que revertir cambios o crearas varias ramas, pero te recomiendo que revises tu pregunta por que esta basada en opiniones y es muy probable que se cierre

Comment: Yo en algunos proyectos trabajo solo y utilizo Git. Te recomiendo que lo utilices aunque al principio puede ser molesto pero es muy útil. Puedes tener diferentes versiones de tu proyecto y copias de seguridad. Si por lo que sea rompes algo en el código puedes volver a una versión anterior de tu programa siempre que quieras.

Comment: Por supuesto, el uso de **git** o de cualquier software de versionado es la principal de las "buenas prácticas" para cualquier desarrollador.

Answer (score 4):

Tal y como te indican en los comentarios, hay algunas preguntas a realizar:

- ¿Trabajas en distintos ordenadores?
- ¿Realizas lanzamientos (*releases*) de tu código?
- ¿Haces cambios importantes de vez en cuando?

Si alguna de estas preguntas tiene un *sí* como respuesta, entonces definitivamente deberías utilizar algún tipo de sistema de control de versiones. Sea git, sea svn, sea lo que sea.

El control de versiones te permite tener el código guardado [remotamente] y documentar su evolución. Te permite marcar (con *tags*) momentos concretos del código que quieres dejar como "buenos" y luego realizar cambios sustanciaciales sin miedo: si algo falla, vuelves a un punto anterior.

Además, también te permite tener distintos desarrollos abiertos en paralelo: una versión estable y que funciona (*master*), otra en desarrollo (*develop*), otras que corrigen algo grave que se rompió (*hotfix*) y otras que son evoluciones del código (*feature*).

Puedes leer sobre una metodología sobre git llamada GitFlow que te puede dar muchas alegrías: https://danielkummer.github.io/git-flow-cheatsheet/

Answer (score 1):

Por supuesto. ***Git***, a veces erróneamente confundido con *Github*, es un software de control de versiones muy útil.

Como ventaja en tu caso particular sería:

- Implementar un sistema de control de versiones o *VCS* de tus proyectos propios a nivel local o algún repositorio no público.
- Tenerlo como copia de seguridad de tu proyecto fuera del equipo de desarrollo.

Como desventaja:

- Esfuerzo extra en aprender su uso y configuración

Answer (score 0):

GIT es un software de control de versiones por lo que no tiene mucho sentido si desarrollas de manera individual.

Ahora bien, si para esa misma web desarrollas versiones, es decir, te piden evolutivos de la web desarrollada por ti, si podría serte útil para guardar cada una de la versiones o evolutivos, para así siempre poder volver a ellas.

Por otro lado, bajo mi punto de vista, tiene mucha utilidad la función "revert" de GIT, ya que si quieres volver a un versión del día anterior, puedes hacerlo de manera muy rápida.

Answer (score 0):

Expongo mi ejemplo. He realizado alguna App en Unity. En casa, trabajo sobre Windows, es donde más cómodo me siento.

Pero cuando viajo, me llevo el MacBook. Para poder continuar con el trabajo, utilizo Git. Siempre que realizo cambios lo actulizo en Git y cuando coja otro PC (el que sea), descargo la versión más reciente.

Aparte de esto, la ventaja que ofrece Git es el poder anotar las actualizaciones y los cambios realizados, manteniendo un registro de versiones.